# Removing documents from MongoDB that have same property values contained within an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm struggling with trying to remove documents from MongoDB 3.0 database  that share 2 property values `profiles.platform` and `profiles.handle` contained within an array.

```
{
    _id: ID
    profiles: [{
        source: {},
        isProfile: Boolean,
        profile: {},
        demographics: {
            male: Number,
            female: Number
        },
        handle: String,
        platform: String
    }]
}
```

I tried using the aggregate framework to get the _ids of documents that share those property values.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$id",
        "duplicates": {
            "$addToSet": "$_id"
        },
        "handles": {
            "$addToSet": "$profiles.profile.handle",
            "$addToSet": "$profiles.profile.platform"
        },
        "count": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
}, {
    "$match": {
        "count": {
            "$gt": 1
        }
    }
}, {
    "$out": "dupes"
}])
```

But that did not work. I got an error

```
{
    "errmsg": "exception: insert for $out failed: { lastOp: Timestamp 1433113685000|1, connectionId: 4856701, err: \"BSONObj size: 56348873 (0x35BD0C9) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: _id: null\", code: 10334, n: 0, ok: 1.0 }",
    "code": 16996,
    "ok": 0
}
```

*Example of Duplicate Documents*
**Document 1**

```
{
    _id: ID
    profiles: [{
        source: {},
        isProfile: true,
        profile: {},
        demographics: {
            male: 1,
            female: 0
        },
        handle:'tom', <--- specific property that is duplicated.
        platform:'myspace' <--- specific property that is duplicated.
    }]
}
```

**Document 2**

```
{
    _id: ID
    profiles: [{
        source: {},
        isProfile: true,
        profile: {},
        demographics: {
            male: 1,
            female: 0
        },
        handle:'tom', <--- specific property that is duplicated.
        platform:'myspace' <--- specific property that is duplicated.
    }]
}
```

*For clarification :* 
I need Document 1 removed because Document 2 has the same values as Document 1. (order of removal does not matter)

Comment: Try removing the "handles..." part of the query. You are hitting the 16MB document limit of Mongo.

Comment: That didn't work. The MongoDB has about 2 million records.

Comment: actually looking at you're bringing back every single document. you're grouping by _id with is unique. You want to group by profile.profile.handle and/or profile.profile.profile. Can you give an example of some duplicate documents?

Comment: I get that. but I was looking for specific properties that are duplicated. It sounds like you need to $unwind your profile array and group on profiles.profile.handle or profiles.profile.platform. you may have to do it in two steps

Comment: I updated the question. I hope the update helps. I'm looking into $unwind and trying to find similar examples. This is a tough one. I wish there were some tools out there for doing this.

Comment: Could you do it like this? use findOne to find a single document you want to keep then use remove with { $and [ {_id: {$neq: document_id }, {handle: "tom"},{ profile: "myspace"} }

Comment: The "unclear" thing I see here is are you asking to remove "duplicates" from "within the array" inside each document or in different documents that "might have" the same properties in one of there array items or not? So what needs to be removed? The document, or the array item inside the document?

Comment: @ThrowsException That approach would only work for single documents. There are many documents thats why I need a better way to remove them such as through aggregate or map reduce. I think the aggregate approach might work fine for this.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I'm try to remove documents that have duplicate `profiles.platform` and `profiles.handle` properties. The end result should either have all the ID of duplicates that need to be removed or even more preferably the end result should remove the documents.

Comment: @user3561036 Sorry for any confusion that the word `record` might have caused. I updated the question to state `document`. I'm trying to remove documents that have both `profiles.platform` and `profiles.handle` values the same. Notice the example documents Document 1 and Document 2. Document 1 needs to be removed because document 2 already has those values. (order of removal does not matter) . Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: That does explain the intent somewhat. But I presume that both "documents" are not "entirely" the same but only share a single item within the contained array that has your "duplicate" properties. In such, do you really want to "merge" the array content of the two documents into a single document with "unique" array items? And then such, what of the top level document properties? Just keep one then?

Comment: @user3561036 you are very much correct. I had troubles wording it the way you said it (english). I don't need to merge the documents, I just need 1 document and remove. They are not duplicates entirely, they share 2 items `profiles.platform` and `profiles.handle` contained within the array.

Comment: I really don't want to advise you without understanding fully. Since the properties are within an "array" that array typically will not contain just one item. So are you in fact saying you just want to throw away any documents that happen to have an item in that array that shares the same properties of one found in another document? Seems a bit brute force. Your examples to date show only a single item in the array, but it is likely not the real world case. Take care to fully explain what you need to achieve is this is easy to misinterpret. Edits to your question are better.

Comment: @user3561036 Yes you are correct. We have a database of 2 million documents but a lot of the documents share those 2 values. If those 2 values are the same, the rest of the information inside the array will also be the same. That being said, if other documents also have those 2 values then they will hold duplicate information. That is why I just need to delete the whole document.

Comment: @mbejda sorry, yes you would need to add the { multi : true } option to the query to remove multiple documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing documents that happen to contain an array item with specific properties matching another document with a shared array item with those properties is not a straight forward operation.

It's probably best to use a combination of the aggregation framework and separate bulk write operations to do so. Here is basically what you want:

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.collection.aggregate([
    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$profiles" },

    // Group on required keys and count
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "handle": "$profiles.handle",
            "platform": "$profiles.platform"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        "ids": { "$addToSet": "$_id" }
    }},

    // Filter anything that is not a duplicate
    { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } }},
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.ids.shift();  // remove the first item to keep
    bulk.remove({ "_id": { "$in": doc.ids } });
    count++;

    // Execute only once every 1000 and re-initialize
    if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collecion.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
});

// Clear any queued
if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

Or language equivalent. Basically, first "identify" the documents that contain duplicates then while "keeping" one document from the match or "excluding" from removal just one of those documents then process the `.remove()` on each "duplicate" in the list.

You could take this further by additionally "de-duplicating" the documents themselves, but this is probably a reasonably safe approach as is with little possible additional overhead.

While handy, I would personally not use **`$out`** here or try to do all the work in the aggregation pipeline. Mostly because "keeping" the whole document in such a grouping would likely blow the 16MB BSON limit, and that it's also a lot of overhead to try and "flag" the duplicate entries and keep just one otherwise.

If you have `$out` then you have a MongoDB that also supports the Bulk operations, so it's best to use them to reduce the traffic.